# How to handle exception when convert string to double

Tags: java, fortify

I am using Fortify code analyzing tool. In my code I am getting string from xml and parse it to double

```
a= Double.parseDouble(b);
```

Tool gives me

```
The program calls a method that parses doubles and can cause the thread to hang.
```

How can I enhance my code ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to catch the possible exeptions and handle them so your code doesn't fall over.
Sometimes the value of B will not parse into a double.

```
try {
  a = Double.parseDouble(b);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  //the parseDouble failed and you need to handle it here
}
```

**Edit:** The 'hanging' issue can be read about here however it's unlikely but worth keeping in mind. http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-hangs-when-converting-2-2250738585072012e-308/

Answer (score 1):

It is a JVM bug, to avoid that use below snippet for parsing to `Double`.

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal(a); // throws NumberFormatException if it is string.
Double b = d.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/denial_of_service_parse_double.html) note, it is only for Java version 6 update 23 and earlier versions. If you are using Java 6 update 24 and above, then believe you can ignore it.